# RabbitMQ notification on queue removal

Tags: .net, rabbitmq

We tried to get a notification when a queue is removed on RabbitMQ in dotnet. The "enable rabbitmq_event_exchange" command of RabbitMQ seems to enable that. https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html

We used the (java) example in the link below as inspiration for the .net implementation.

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-event-exchange/blob/master/examples/java/QueueEvents.java

This is the basic function we implemented so far:

```
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
using System;

namespace *.QueueListener
{
    public class CustomEventingBasicConsumer : EventingBasicConsumer
    {
        public CustomEventingBasicConsumer(IModel model) : base(model)
        {
        }

        public override void HandleBasicDeliver(string consumerTag, ulong deliveryTag, bool 
            redelivered, string exchange, string routingKey, IBasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(routingKey);
            base.HandleBasicDeliver(consumerTag, deliveryTag, redelivered, exchange, routingKey, 
                properties, body);
        }
    }
}
```

We expected to get notified by the routing key. As happens in the java example with `if (event.equals("queue.created"))` However, there are no messages logged, besides the one published by myself at the other side.

Any ideas on how we can receive these messages?

(We are using RabbitMQ 3.7.8)

Comment: Have you enabled the `rabbitmq_event_exchange` plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did u connect to the amq.rabbitmq.event exchange? events concerning queue deletes are published on this exchange

Its possible to connect to this exchange by using ExchangeDeclarePassive.

```
    public static void AddChannelToEventConnection()
    {
        _eventChannel = PublisherConnection.CreateModel();
        _eventChannel.ExchangeDeclarePassive("amq.rabbitmq.event");

        _eventChannel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
        _eventConsumer = new CustomEventingBasicConsumer(_eventChannel);
    }
```

After that all queues on which you want to be notified need to be binden to the exchange

```
_eventChannel.QueueBind("queue", "amq.rabbitmq.event", "queue", null);
```

Finally u need to create a custom event consumer

```
public class CustomEventingBasicConsumer : EventingBasicConsumer
{
    public CustomEventingBasicConsumer(IModel model) : base(model)
    {
    }

    public override void HandleBasicCancelOk(string consumerTag)
    {
        base.HandleBasicCancelOk(consumerTag);
    }
    public override void HandleBasicCancel(string consumerTag)
    {
        base.HandleBasicCancel(consumerTag);
    }

    public override void HandleBasicDeliver(string consumerTag, ulong deliveryTag, bool redelivered, string exchange, string routingKey, IBasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
    {
        base.HandleBasicDeliver(consumerTag, deliveryTag, redelivered, exchange, routingKey, properties, body);
    }

    public override void HandleBasicConsumeOk(string consumerTag)
    {
        base.HandleBasicConsumeOk(consumerTag);
    }

}
```

If you put a breakpoint in HandleBasicCancel You will see that on queue deletion the breakpoint will be hit with the consumerTag of the queue